# nohup "does not work" MPIrun

Tags: linux, nohup

I am trying to use the "nohup" command to avoid killing a background process when exiting the terminal on linux MATE.

The process I want to run is a MPIrun process and I use the following command:

```
nohup mpirun -np 8 solverName -parallel >log 2>&1
```

when I leave the terminal, the processes running on the different cores are killed.

Also another thing I remarked in the log file, is that if I try to just run the following command

```
mpirun -np 8 solverName -parallel >log 2>&1
```

and then to CTRL+Z (stopping the process) the log file indicates :

```
Forwarding signal 20 to job
```

and I am unable to actually stop the mpirun command. So I guess there is something I don't understand in what I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job run in the background is still owned by your login shell (the `nohup` command doesn't exit until the `mpirun` command terminates), so it gets signalled when you disconnect.  This script (I call it `bk`) is what I use:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# @(#)$Id: bk.sh,v 1.9 2008/06/25 16:43:25 jleffler Exp $"
#
# Run process in background
# Immune from logoffs -- output to file log

(
echo "Date: `date`"
echo "Command: $*"
nice nohup "$@"
echo "Completed: `date`"
echo
) >>${LOGFILE:=log} 2>&1 &
```

(If you're into curiosities, note the careful use of `$*` and `"$@"`. The `nice` runs the job at a lower priority when I'm not there.  And version 1.1 was checked into version control — SCCS at the time — on 1987-08-10.)

For your process, you'd run:

```
$ bk mpirun -np 8 solverName -parallel
$
```

The prompt returns almost immediately.  The key differences between what is in that code and what you do direct from the command line are:

1. There's a sub-process for the shell script, which terminates promptly.
2. The script itself runs the command in a sub-shell in background.

Between them, these mean that the process is not interfered with by your login shell; it doesn't know about the grandchild process.

Running direct on the command line, you'd write:

```
(nohup mpirun -np 8 solverName -parallel >log 2>&1 &)
```

The parentheses start a subshell; the sub-shell runs `nohup` in the background with I/O redirection and terminates.  The continuing command is a grandchild of your login shell and is not interfered with by your login shell.

I'm not an expert in [`mpirun`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man1/mpirun.1.php), never having used it, so there's a chance it does something I'm not expecting.  My impression from the manual page is that it acts more or less like a regular process even though it can run multiple other processes, possibly on multiple nodes.  That is, it runs the other processes but monitors and coordinates them and only exits when its children are complete.  If that's correct, then what I've outlined is accurate enough.

Answer (score 1):

To kill the process you need the following command.
first:

`$ jobs -l`

this gives you the PID of the process like this

`[1]+ 47274 Running     nohup mpirun -np 8 solverName -parallel >log 2>&1`

then execute the following command to kill the process.

`kill -9 {program PID i.e 47274 }`

this will help you with killing the process.

note that ctrl+Z does not kill the process but it suspends it.

for the first part of the question, I recommend to try this command and see if it works or not.

`nohup nohup mpirun -n 8 --your_flags ./compited_solver_name  > Output.txt &`

it worked for me. 
tell us if it doesn't work for you.